# Account not deleted

Tags: support, user-accounts, deletions, deleted-accounts

25 hours after my account was scheduled for deletion, the account is still active. I tried deleting my answers manually but it is not possible in most cases, same for questions. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe MO is like the Hotel California, where you can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.

Comment: From the FAQ post [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999): "If your account has cast a lot of votes, it will not be deleted approximately after the 24-hour timer expires, as above. Deletion will be held up while a Stack Exchange employee checks your account ... The queue of accounts awaiting deletion is [processed every Wednesday and Friday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326969), excluding holidays. This means that if your account falls into this queue, it could take up to three business days for your deletion request to be processed."

Comment: Ok. Today is Wednesday.

Comment: Thank you Martin!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obsolete now.

Answer (score 7):

Mark, I've sent Community Management a message. I trust they can sort out what is going on with your account.

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: @MarkSapir: This might be because of the nature of your account. Months ago a user from math.stack told me that high rep accounts are more difficult to delete and that the user needed to change the user name to their id number, to contact a moderator, etc. I don't exactly recall, but that was the idea.

Comment: If you know Xander Henderson, he was the one that said this.

Comment: I have contacted the moderators (4 times by email and posting two questions). These people can do nothing but insult me and contact other moderators. They did not respond to my emails.

Comment: I do not know Henderson. Perhaps the moderators should contact him. He seems to know a lot of useful info.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Back then I asked him how did he know that info, but he never replied, let me search for that post.

Comment: @MarkSapir Here it is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30748/extending-the-grace-period-for-account-deletion?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MarkSapir: well idk what happened (with the suspension) but so far of what I have seen, no one has insulted you. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Mark, I am sorry, but I know of only two (private) messages from you, not four. I don't know why you are having trouble doing what you say you are trying to do. Nor do I understand why you've said that you reached a 404 page for the link to instructions on how to delete: I tested it out myself, and it seemed fine. It's here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account (maybe other users can verify whether they get a 404). Nor do I understand why you think we are insulting you. All I was saying is that CM can take a while to respond.

Comment: There were 4 same messages "please delete my account". I did not receive an answer. If you click at the link Delete profile in the file you sent me you get 404 and I got 404 while my account was suspended which you are supposed to know. You lied and insulted me in one of the comments here and before.

Comment: Ah. This could be software related. All we see is two messages. The first "please delete" we responded to (see below). I can quote back to you the second message we see, but basically you said "please delete my account" again, after we said to you that we're not going to do that, this has to be an action you perform yourself (words to that effect). If a CM comes by, I'm sure he/she could corroborate. Still don't follow the 404 business you allege. But, I think I'm done.

Comment: @MarkSapir Todd's help page link above goes to meta.stackexchange.com . If you then directly click the "Delete profile" link on that page, it will attempt to delete your meta.stackexchange profile, which is presumably impossible as you don't seem to have a meta.stackexchange profile in the first place. To delete your MO profile, you have to first navigate to your MO profile, and click the "Delete profile" link *there*, following the instructions.

Comment: Direct link: https://mathoverflow.net/users/delete/6976

Comment: Thanks, Emil. It never occurred to me that anyone would misinterpret the instruction at that help page, but that might well explain the 404 that Mark was seeing.

Comment: I should probably also explain what I meant by software related issue. I think it's a feature, not a bug, that in the moderator private message system, if one account fires off several messages in succession, only the first is received. It's easy to guess why that feature would be implemented. But I think this explains why the mods see only two messages from Mark in their inbox.

Comment: This does not explain why you did not reply to any of the messages.

Comment: Mark, there was only one message that we got after your first, which basically repeated "please delete my account" (I could quote it exactly if you want me to capture the tone), which came after we said precisely that we weren't going to do that. To be honest, I don't think any of us saw the point of repeating ourselves. We did of course reply to your first message (otherwise we wouldn't have gotten the second, as I explained a moment ago).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: If you click on this direct link, you get error404 because you do not own the account. I got the same error because a suspended account does not belong to the owner.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: The moderators never sent me replies about deletion of my account. The suspension   notice had an option of replying which I used. So the only true statement in your comment  is that mods chose to ignore my messages.

Comment: They did not as Trimble said.

Comment: Once again, Mark, and this is the last time I'll say this: we saw just two private messages from you, **and that's it**. We responded to the first and gave you a link with information on how to delete, and then we chose not to get into a back and forth where you keep asking us to delete your account, because we already said we weren't going to do that. Really, this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Endless rudeness and noise.